# Separate a list of data frames into multiple data frames

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, split

I have a list of data frames that was created using a user-defined function -

`a = list(map(test, cat_feature_names))`

where

`cat_feature_names = ['Brand', 'Variety', 'Style', 'Country', 'Stars', 'Top Ten']`

and the function is this

```
def test(col):
    vc = df[col].value_counts().rename_axis('unique_values').reset_index(name='counts')
    vc['feature'] = col
    vc['frequency']=round((vc['counts']/(vc['counts'].sum())*100),2)
    vc = vc[['feature','unique_values','counts','frequency']]
    no_of_unique = len(vc)
    return vc
```

Now, I need to separate the contents of "a" into multiple data frames that are of separate size and shape. I need to do this dynamically. All I am able to do now is extract one data frame at a time, like so

`a[0]`

A for loop would not work because there might be a very large number of data frames in the list "a".

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Following for loop will break your list into multiple dataframes. globals() will be used to to name it like df_0, df_1 and so on..

```
for i in range(len(your_list)):
    globals()[f"df_{i}"] = your_list[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you're separating a df in multiple dataframes, giving a column name as parameter to your mapping function `test`.

One solution might be to store you dataframes in a dictionary, using the column name as key:

```
df_dict = dict(zip(cat_feature_names, map(test, cat_feature_names)))
```

You can then access each dataframe with `df_dict[col_name]`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i found to work :

```py
for i in range(len(lst_distances)):
    globals()[f"df_{i}"] = lst_distances[i] # adds all distances to different lists based on their index
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.